# change axis scaling step size in ggplot2

Tags: r

i have an R script which generate a `geom_tile` plot exactly as i want.

but the problem is that the axis step size is so big `e.g(4000 - 8000 - 12000 - ...)`

i tried `scale_x_continuous('Xaxis',limits = c(...))` and `scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10)`

but it only make limits to the data.

what should i do to minimize this step size on the axis?

```
e.g (500 - 1000 - 1500 - 2000 - 2500 ....etc)
```

thankk you

Comment: Setting `scale_x_continuous(breaks = ...)` _is_ the way to do this. You just have to provide it with the specific break points you want to see.

Comment: @joran: thank you. can i do something like this? 
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,10000,50))

Answer (score 34):

Since no one has posted an answer yet, only comments, here it is :)

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10000, 500))
```

Source: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html